# How to forward iPhone messages to Macbook or iPod?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ipod, messages, sim

I'm currently studying abroad in England. I have an iPod touch, iPhone 5, and Macbook Air. I recently took the SIM card out of my iPhone and received a UK Sim card so I can use data and texting here in London. However, I obviously got a new phone number  with that. I was fine with having a new phone number and simply using iMessage on my laptop or iPod touch seeing as all my friends from home have that. However, my US messages are not working now that my iPhone is associated with a new number. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Using e-mailaddress for iMessage doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Your icloud should still work - meaning FaceTime should still be operational - for the rest you have to rely on your MacBook and iPod - iPhone with a new number is useless - or just use your US sim knowing that you will be charged long distance roaming etc.  I'm an expat a long time - we have our limits in communicating back home - stay with your MacBook. Safe and not sorry